# Why don't matter bosons, like any non-ionized atoms with even numbers of protons and neutrons, fall through each other like ghosts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, bosons, matter

Obviously, two chunks of pure Iron-56 won't pass through each other like photons go right through each other...

Why is that?

Is it because of the fact that composite fermions are made of smaller fermions, which which repel each other?

What about the background quantum foam?  Particles are more likely to pop into existence, and stay in existence, when near a strong point in the QED field, such as near a particle, right?  Could that create the repulsion?

Comment: Why should they?

Comment: What did you read to make you believe that all bosons act like immaterial particles?

Comment: I suspect it's because the obverse of the Pauli exclusion principle appears to say that an integer-spin atom could occupy exactly the same quantum state as another integer-spin atom -- and that, in turn implies the same position.  I'm actually kinda interested in the distinction myself, although I suspect it has something to do with atoms being made of smaller fermions.

Comment: @TimWescott I think your hunch is correct.

Comment: There is a questionable assumption: is there any experimental evidence that ghosts do not interact with each other?